# GeoIP.dat.gz and GeoLiteCity.dat.gz not longer available? Getting 404 trying to load it

Tags: nginx, geoip, maxmind, geoip2

Started couple days ago i can't download

http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCountry/GeoIP.dat.gz
http://geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoLiteCity.dat.gz

databases which i use to enable [ngx_http_geoip_module](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_geoip_module.html) module.

It was free and available all the time but now. Does anybody know anything about recent changes with this DB?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Maxmind no longer supports Geolite legacy, just Geolite2 : 
https://blog.maxmind.com/2018/01/02/discontinuation-of-the-geolite-legacy-databases/

Answer (score 17):

You can convert MaxMind GeoLite2 Database to the old legacy format with [this script](https://github.com/sherpya/geolite2legacy):

Example: `./geolite2legacy.py -i GeoLite2-Country-CSV.zip -f geoname2fips.csv -o GeoIP.dat`

BTW - there is a site where you can find new data on the legacy format, here:
https://www.miyuru.lk/geoiplegacy
(the files there were built using with this script)

Answer (score 5):

you can use an alternative cdn site:

https://mirrors-cdn.liferay.com/geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/

Here you'll find:

https://mirrors-cdn.liferay.com/geolite.maxmind.com/download/geoip/database/GeoIP.dat.gz

Comment: The database in CDN has not been updated for a while. You should remove this answer to avoid confusion.

Comment: @sean-booker I have downloaded that .gz file, but it is corrupted, do you have any other suggestion, Thanks!

Comment: JFYI. Found this site (https://www.miyuru.lk/geoiplegacy) hosting updated dat files.

Answer (score 1):

I published a docker image that hosts a legacy database you can use too, based on the geolite2legacy.py script, updated every week inside container.

https://hub.docker.com/r/peterlh/geoip-legacy

Answer (score 0):

I use awk to parse country and network information from `whois`.

```
#!/bin/bash
IP=$1

if out=$(grep $IP /tmp/mygeoip)
then
    echo "$out" | awk '{$1="";print}'
    exit
fi

if [[ ($IP =~ ^10\.) || ($IP =~ ^192.168\.) || ($IP =~ ^172.16\.) ]]
then
    echo "LAN"
    exit 0
fi

#  __^__             __^__
# ( ___ )-----------( ___ )
#  | / | AWK version | \ |
#  |___|             |___|
# (_____)-----------(_____)

result=$(whois $IP | awk '/country/ {country=$2} /netname/ {netname=$2} END {print country,netname}')
echo $IP $result >> /tmp/mygeoip
echo $result

$ net.ip.geo 192.168.90.238
LAN
$ net.ip.geo 92.247.20.226
BG MTELNET
$ net.ip.geo 129.45.92.28
DZ Optimum-Telecom-Algeria
$
```

It uses a temporary cache in `/tmp/mygeoip` so that query on same IP is looked up in the cache not from `whois`.